# Create a new column based on condition on other two columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID     PRICE      DURATION
1      10         30
2      200        730
3      40         60
4      300        400
5      100        180
```

From the above data, I would like to create a new column PRICE_PER_YEAR based on below condition.

```
if DURATION < 370, then df['PRICE_PER_YEAR'] = df['PRICE']/ df['DURATION'] * 365

else df['PRICE_PER_YEAR'] = df['PRICE']
```

Expected Output:

```
ID     PRICE      DURATION      PRICE_PER_YEAR
1      10         30            121.66
2      200        730           200
3      40         60            243.33
4      300        400           300
5      100        180           202.77
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```py
>>> df['PRICE_PER_YEAR'] = np.where(df.DURATION < 370, df['PRICE']/ df['DURATION']*365, df['PRICE'])
>>> df
   ID  PRICE  DURATION  PRICE_PER_YEAR
0   1     10        30      121.666667
1   2    200       730      200.000000
2   3     40        60      243.333333
3   4    300       400      300.000000
4   5    100       180      202.777778
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['PRICE_PER_YEAR'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['PRICE']/ x['DURATION'] * 365 if x['DURATION'] < 370 
     else x['PRICE'], axis = 1)
```